# How does the HDFS Client knows the block size while writing?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

The HDFS Client is outside the HDFS Cluster. When the HDFS Client write the file to hadoop the HDFS clients split the files into blocks and then it will write the block to datanode.

The question here is how the HDFS Client knows the Blocksize ? Block size is configured in the Name node and the HDFS Client has no idea about the block size then how it will split the file into blocks ?

Comment: The client contacts the namenode before writing to the datanodes

Comment: so what you are saying is when the client first makes the RPC call using create("log.txt") for this call the name node will return the block size of the hdfs rite?

Comment: Replace `log.txt` with any file name, then yes, but there are more steps associated with the process.

Comment: is there any document or videos available to explaining the process.The hadoop definitive guide or youtube videos never said that the name node will inform the client to split the block based on the block size configured in the Namenode configuraiton

Comment: Hadoop definitive guide 3rd or 4th edition. "Chapter 3: Anatomy of a File Write"

Answer (score 3):

HDFS is designed in a way where the block size for a particular file is part of the MetaData.

Let's just check what does this mean?

The client can tell the NameNode that it will put data to HDFS with a particular block size.
The client has its own hdfs-site.xml that can contain this value, and can specify it on a per-request basis as well using the -Ddfs.blocksize parameter.

If the client configuration does not define this parameter, then it defaults to the org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSConfigKeys.DFS_BLOCK_SIZE_DEFAULT value which is 128MB.

NameNode can throw an error for the client if it specifies a blocksize that is smaller then dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size (1MB by default).

There is nothing magical in this, NameNode does know nothing about the data and let the client to decide the optimal splitting, as well as to define the replication factor for blocks of a file.

Comment: Please correct my understanding..
What you are saying is Client has hdfs.site.xml which has namenode connection as well as block size.The client hdfs.site.xml can have block size like 128mb or 256mb...This configuration will split the file and which will be written in the datanode...If the Client doesnt have the blocksize  then it will be default size 128mb which also read from the client side(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSConfigKeys.DFS_BLOCK_SIZE_DEFAULT). Is this correct ?

Comment: Lets say if the client size blocksize configuaration in the dhfs.site.xml is 256mb and in the Namenode the block size configuration in the hdfs.site.xml is 128mb what will happen ? ..here the block size in the Namenode is lesser than block size in the client...what will happen in the viceversa case...

Comment: Sorry I did not had the time to check back earlier. So if the client side config defines 256MB as block size, then the file will be created with that block size. The NN side setting does nothing about that, as the block size is part of the INode data. NN only enforce the minimum block size. You can check this on grepcode, in the client the blocksize is dermined based on the config on the client side, and it is sent to the NN that pushes it all the way to the INodeFile object stores the inode data. Check the create methods in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.

Comment: block size comes from the client side via rpc calls. You can track it in the class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient (search for defaultblocksize and how it gets its value. NN is not a factor on that at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Some more details below (from the Hadoop Definitive Guide 4th edition)

[image: Anatomy of File Write from Hadoop Definitive Guide]

"The client creates the file by calling create() on DistributedFileSystem (step 1 in
Figure 3-4). DistributedFileSystem makes an RPC call to the namenode to create a new
file in the filesystem’s namespace, with no blocks associated with it (step 2). The
namenode performs various checks to make sure the file doesn’t already exist and that the
client has the right permissions to create the file. If these checks pass, the namenode
makes a record of the new file; otherwise, file creation fails and the client is thrown an
IOException. The DistributedFileSystem returns an FSDataOutputStream for the client
to start writing data to. Just as in the read case, FSDataOutputStream wraps a
DFSOutputStream, which handles communication with the datanodes and namenode.
**As the client writes data (step 3), the DFSOutputStream splits it into packets, which it writes to an internal queue called the data queue.**"

Adding more info in response to comment on this post:

Here is a sample client program to copy a file to HDFS (Source-Hadoop Definitive Guide)

```
public class FileCopyWithProgress {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String localSrc = args[0];
    String dst = args[1];

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localSrc));

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);
    OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(dst), new Progressable() {
        public void progress() {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    });

    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);
}
```

}

If you look at create() method implementation in FileSystem class, it has getDefaultBlockSize() as one of its arguments, which inturn fetches the values from configuration which is turn is provided by the namenode.
This is how client gets to know the block size configured on hadoop cluster.

Hope this helps

Comment: I read this ..but there is no where mentioned that how the client know whether Block size is 64MB or 128MB which is configured in the NameNode. How the DFSOutputStream splits the data how it knows the block size....Lets say I am the client and I want to write a file to the HDFS ...and lets say the file doesnt not exists in the HDFS ..the check pass but how I will know the block size configured in the HDFS..based the information only I can split the files into blocks...

Comment: Client does not get the blocksize from the NN, it is not part of any protocol, client has its own configuration, and it is its own sole right to define the blocksize with which it want to store the file. getDefaultBlockSize is a client side operation that does not go to the NameNode just to the local Configuration object, or the hardwired constant of 128MB if the config does not contain dfs.blocksize or dfs.block.size (the latter is deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, When you do client URI deploy, it will place server URI into Client or you download and manually replace in client. So whenever client request for info, it will go to the NameNode and fetch the required info or place new info on DataNodes.

P.S: Client = EdgeNode